# Imagery Alpha and Mask channels: when should each be used?

Tags: raster, multi-band

Gdal supports both [Mask](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc15_nodatabitmask.html) and Alpha channels. In what circumstances are they best applied? How to choose between them?

For example the [nearblack](https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html#nearblack) utility to change image collar pixels to nodata can use both `-setalpha` and `-setmask` for this purpose. They seem to be functionally identical. Does it matter which is used? Also both can be used at the same time. Does this accidentally arrive from how it's implemented or is there a purpose for using simultaneously?